# Can you pin parse files/ images to the local datastore?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

If not what is a good way to cache images locally?

-- Note: I am coding for Android.

Answer (score 0):

[`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

> Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled
>   automatically by Picasso:
>
> Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
>   Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
>   Automatic memory and disk caching.

When you want to send the image to your cloud, you could use `ParseFile` in conjunction with `Picasso`, get the bytes from the image and `save()` or `saveInBackground()`.

Comment: but what if if i want to query in advance so that if the user is offline I can show them a set of images?

Comment: @Sree I didn't quite get that. Gimme a specific scenario. What type of images are you planning to show if the user is offline?

Comment: So let's say that the User wants to save a map (this is a jpg file) so that he or she can see it even when they are offline. The user can press a button and all the maps pertaining to an area are saved. In this scenario, I would need a way to cache the file itself without necessarily displaying it.

Comment: Picasso can do it. Read up on it.